# TypeScript compiler not detecting variable type correctly

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I'm attempting to use a `for (let x in obj)` loop but the TypeScript compiler does not recognise the type of `x` correctly... it always assumes it is of type `string`.

In the example below, the type of `obj` outside the `for` loop is detected correctly. The TypeScript compiler recognizes it as a `number`. However, the `obj` inside the `for` loop is recognized as a `string` when it should be a `number`.

```
let myObj: { [key: number]: number } = { 0: 43, 5: 23 };

let obj = myObj[0]; // let obj: number

for (let obj in myObj) {
    if (obj == 1) {
        // ^ [ts] Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.
        // TypeScript compiler thinks 'obj' is of type 'string' when used in `for in` loop.
    }
}
```

This casues errors in my code and I'm not sure how to work around this issue. Is it something I'm doing wrong, or is it a TypeScript bug?

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that `for k in o` loops over `o`'s property *keys*, not its *values*, right?  Additionally, JavaScript only really allows *strings* as property keys, and will silently coerce non-strings to strings:

From [MDN's documentation for accessing properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Property_names):

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method.

So that means that TypeScript is actually correct when it types `obj` as `string`:

```
for (let obj in myObj) {
    console.log(typeof obj); // "string"
    if (obj === "1") // okay now {
      myObj[obj] = 123; // okay, property value is a number
    }
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: So if I wanted to use the key as a number, I'd be required to use something like `parseInt` or `parseFloat`?

Comment: Yes, something like that (e.g., `Number(obj)` or `+obj`)